# How to select with a SQL query a date and for each 2 week pay period

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

How do I select `6/20/2014` and every pay date (every two weeks) before this date to the beginning of 2010?  I also want to be able to select `6/20/2014` and every pay date (every 2 weeks) after this date to the end of 2020.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [Numbers table](http://dataeducation.com/you-require-a-numbers-table/):

```
SELECT TOP 10000 IDENTITY(int,1,1) AS Number
INTO NumbersTest
FROM sys.objects s1
CROSS JOIN sys.objects s2
ALTER TABLE NumbersTest ADD CONSTRAINT PK_NumbersTest PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Number)
```

Then

```
declare @startDate date = '6/20/2014'

--Dates from 1/1/2010 to 6/20/2014
select DATEADD(wk, -2 * (n.Number - 1), @startDate)
from NumbersTest n
where DATEADD(wk, -2 * (n.Number - 1), @startDate) >= '1/1/2010'

--Dates from 6/20/2014 to 12/31/2020
select DATEADD(wk, 2 * (n.Number - 1), @startDate)
from NumbersTest n
where DATEADD(wk, 2 * (n.Number - 1), @startDate) <= '12/31/2020'
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1fc6f/3/0)

Answer (score 2):

The SQL below can give you the answer to the first part of your question.  Same principals can be used to get the answer to the second part.

```
declare @startDate as date = '20140620';

with myCte1 as
(
    select @startDate as dt
    union all
    select DATEADD(week, -2, dt)
    from myCte1
    where dt > '20100112'
)

select m.dt
from myCte1 as m
option (maxrecursion 1000)
```